# Azure Mobile Service Login After Publishing In Mode Debug

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I created an azure mobile Service and published it by using Visual Studio. I selected as the publish Option "Debug". After that I have added myself as the owner.

I checked my Project by typing in the URL in the browser myproject.azurewebsites.net. When I'm trying to look at the api documentation (myproject.azurewebsite.net/help) there is a prompt, where the Server is asking for username and Password.

I thought this should be no Problem and tried to Login with my Microsoft account but it didn't work.

The (self describing) Response I get after typing the wrong Information is:

```
{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

So now to my question(s):

- how can I lookup my username and Password?
- which username and Password shall I use - in the sense of how to set/get the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For being able to do that, you should create the connection between your Mobile App and authentication provider you want to use. Then, after you set up the connection, you can use the object model that will represent your user.
Please, refer to that link for more information [about authentication model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-auth/).